# bind number value with ngb-timepicker angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bind, timepicker

I have a `priceRule`object which contains 4 attributes :

```js
public hourStartTime: number,
public minuteStartTime: number,
public hourEndTime: number,
public minuteEndTime: number,
```

And two `nbg-timepicker` :

```
<!-- timepicker to pick the start -->
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="...">

</ngb-timepicker>

<!-- timepicker to pick the end -->
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="...">

</ngb-timepicker>
```

I don't know what to type to bind my values ( hourStartTime and minuteStartTim with the first timepicker, hourEndTime and minuteEndTime with the second timepicker ).

Comment: As opposed to direct two-way binding, have you tried separating into attribute binding on one side and event binding on the other? Using `[ngModel]` to create a valid `time` object from your `priceRule` object, and then binding to the `(change)` event to update your `priceRule` object? It's not very elegant, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, you can define time like this:

```
time = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ngb-timepicker [ngModel]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

In your case:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-timepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/timepicker-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  time = any;
  priceRule: any;
  constructor() {
    this.priceRule.hourStartTime = 13;
    this.priceRule.minuteStartTime = 50;    
    time = { hour: this.priceRule.hourStartTime, minute: this.priceRule.minuteStartTime }
  }
}
```

**Update**

Since `ngb-timepicker` expects an object of type

```
{ time: number, minute: number }
```

So, if you don't want to use an extra variable, then you'll have to change the structure of `priceRule` a little bit. So
Instead of

```
export class PriceRule {
 public hourStartTime: number,
 public minuteStartTime: number,
 public hourEndTime: number,
 public minuteEndTime: number,
}
```

It would be :

```
export class PriceRule {
  public startTime: { hour: number, minute: number };
  public endTime: { hour: number, minute: number };
}
```

And in your component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-timepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/timepicker-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  time = any;
  priceRule: any;
  constructor() {
    this.priceRule.startTime = { hour: 13, minute: 4 }    
  }
}
```

In in your HTML:

```
<ngb-timepicker [ngModel]="priceRule.startTime"></ngb-timepicker>
```

Comment: yes but values ( hour, minute ) are stocked in my Object `priceRule`

Comment: Can you explain

Comment: I don't want to create a new variable to do that. I have my values stocked in my `priceRule` object and I just want them to be binded with the `ngb-timepicker` that's it. If I do what you told me to do, it's this `time` variable which will be binded, not my values of my `priceRule` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NgbTimeStruct` interface from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/timepicker/ngb-time-struct.ts

```js
time: NgbTimeStruct;
...
this.time = { hour: 12, minute: 14, second: 0 };
```

and your template

```html
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="initialTime"></ngb-timepicker>
```